# 404 error with cgi-bin perl

Tags: mysql, wordpress, perl, cgi-bin

**Update**

To try and simplify the problem, I made the following file (dbtest.pl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";
print "hi";
```

I would expect it to load the page and say "hi". However, it gives me a 404 error from wordpress. Is it just a case of there is something wrong with using DBD::mysql? Is it not installed properly on my server perhaps?

**Original post**

Up until recently I have had some simple perl working to update a database column to 'processed' once transaction has been made.

For some reason this has stopped working. At first I thought it was something to do with a wordpress installation that is running for the website root and mod_rewrite, because when I tried to access the pl directly it rerouted me to the wordpress 404 page.

However when I started testing with basic perl 'print 'hello world' type messages everything seemed to work.

It seems to be that when I include the line 'use DBD::mysql;' the page will redirect to 404. If I remove that line, the following code works (up until it tries to access the database).

If anyone can see something wrong in the following code, or has suggestions on how to fix the problem, it would be much appreciated! (also, if I need to refine the question, let me know)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# PERL MODULES WE WILL BE USING
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
use CGI;
use MIME::Lite;
use Email::Valid;
use HTML::Entities ();
use CGI qw/:standard/;

$ok_chars = 'a-zA-Z0-9 ,-@';
$messageclean = "";
foreach $param_name ( param() ) {
    $_ = HTML::Entities::decode( param($param_name) );
    $_ =~ s/[^$ok_chars]//go;
    param($param_name,$_);
}

local $query = new CGI;

# read in the cgi fields.
local $input_payment_reference = $query->param('payment_reference');
local $input_email = $query->param('Your_Email');
local $reference = $query->param('Transaction_ID');

# the reference is the last couple of digits, without the first 2 characters
$input_payment_reference = substr($reference, 2);

$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
                 To      =>$input_email,
                 From       =>'admin@admin.com',
                 Subject =>'Message',
                 Type    =>'multipart/related'
                 );
    $msg->attach(Type => 'text/html',
                 Data => qq{
<html>
<body>
<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">
<tr><td style="background: #eee;"><strong>Transaction ID:</strong> </td><td style="background:#fff;"> $input_payment_reference </td></tr>
</table>
<p>Thank you for registering</p>
</body>
</html>
                            }
                 );                                                             

# HTTP HEADER
print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";

# CONFIG VARIABLES
$platform = "mysql";
$database = "database";
$host = "localhost";
$port = "3306";
$tablename = "table";
$user = "user";
$pw = "password";

# DATA SOURCE NAME
$dsn = "dbi:$platform:$database:$host:$port";

# PERL DBI CONNECT
$connect = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw) or die "Can't connect to the DB: $DBI::errstr\n";

# PREPARE THE QUERY
$query = "UPDATE $tablename SET orderStatus = 'processed'
WHERE transactionID = '".$input_payment_reference."'";

$query_handle = $connect->prepare($query);

# EXECUTE THE QUERY
$query_handle->execute();

# SEND EMAIL
$msg->send();
```

Comment: I would suggest that you look into your server error log for the exact message that is being given.  Obviously something isn't working with your database connection, so maybe get that working in a standalone script first for quicker feedback?

Comment: You can use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); which should display errors & make it easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I've tried some changes, and I didn't even get as far as trying to access the db. Using CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);  doesn't seem to make an impact on the new test code...

Comment: You should add `use strict`, `use warnings` and even `use diagnostics` to get more informations about what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks again for more ideas. I tried using all of those and yet I'm still left with the wordpress 404 page. The error log doesn't seem to say anything. I may just have to try some more tests on another host and see if it is something to do with the server, rather than the code.